# OpenAI gym: How to get complete list of ATARI environments

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have installed OpenAI `gym` and the ATARI environments. I know that I can find all the ATARI games in the [documentation](https://gym.openai.com/envs#atari) but is there a way to do this in Python, **without** printing any other environments (e.g. NOT the classic control environments)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `list_games()` on `atari_py`:

```
>>> import atari_py as ap
>>> game_list = ap.list_games()
>>> print(sorted(game_list))
<<< ['adventure',
     'air_raid',
     'alien',
     'amidar',
     'assault',
     'asterix',
     'asteroids',
     'atlantis',
     'bank_heist',
     'battle_zone',
     'beam_rider',
     'berzerk',
     'bowling',
     'boxing',
     'breakout',
     'carnival',
     'centipede',
     'chopper_command',
     # ...
     ]
```

Answer (score 2):

To save others the bother:

'adventure', 'air_raid', 'alien', 'amidar', 'assault', 'asterix', 'asteroids', 'atlantis', 'bank_heist', 'battle_zone', 'beam_rider', 'berzerk', 'bowling', 'boxing', 'breakout', 'carnival', 'centipede', 'chopper_command', 'crazy_climber', 'defender', 'demon_attack', 'double_dunk', 'elevator_action', 'enduro', 'fishing_derby', 'freeway', 'frostbite', 'gopher', 'gravitar', 'hero', 'ice_hockey', 'jamesbond', 'journey_escape', 'kaboom', 'kangaroo', 'krull', 'kung_fu_master', 'montezuma_revenge', 'ms_pacman', 'name_this_game', 'phoenix', 'pitfall', 'pong', 'pooyan', 'private_eye', 'qbert', 'riverraid', 'road_runner', 'robotank', 'seaquest', 'skiing', 'solaris', 'space_invaders', 'star_gunner', 'tennis', 'time_pilot', 'tutankham', 'up_n_down', 'venture', 'video_pinball', 'wizard_of_wor', 'yars_revenge', 'zaxxon'

Updated in 10.12.17

Comment: list is too long for a comment

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for `ALE` specific, use the following code.

```
import gym

tree = gym.envs.registry.all()._mapping.tree["ALE"]

env_names = [f"ALE/{name}-v5" for name, value in tree.items() if "ram" not in name]
```

This will output:

```
['ALE/Tetris-v5', 'ALE/Adventure-v5', 'ALE/AirRaid-v5', 'ALE/Alien-v5', 'ALE/Amidar-v5', 'ALE/Assault-v5', 'ALE/Asterix-v5', 'ALE/Asteroids-v5', 'ALE/Atlantis-v5', 'ALE/Atlantis2-v5', 'ALE/Backgammon-v5', 'ALE/BankHeist-v5', 'ALE/BasicMath-v5', 'ALE/BattleZone-v5', 'ALE/BeamRider-v5', 'ALE/Berzerk-v5', 'ALE/Blackjack-v5', 'ALE/Bowling-v5', 'ALE/Boxing-v5', 'ALE/Breakout-v5', 'ALE/Carnival-v5', 'ALE/Casino-v5', 'ALE/Centipede-v5', 'ALE/ChopperCommand-v5', 'ALE/CrazyClimber-v5', 'ALE/Crossbow-v5', 'ALE/Darkchambers-v5', 'ALE/Defender-v5', 'ALE/DemonAttack-v5', 'ALE/DonkeyKong-v5', 'ALE/DoubleDunk-v5', 'ALE/Earthworld-v5', 'ALE/ElevatorAction-v5', 'ALE/Enduro-v5', 'ALE/Entombed-v5', 'ALE/Et-v5', 'ALE/FishingDerby-v5', 'ALE/FlagCapture-v5', 'ALE/Freeway-v5', 'ALE/Frogger-v5', 'ALE/Frostbite-v5', 'ALE/Galaxian-v5', 'ALE/Gopher-v5', 'ALE/Gravitar-v5', 'ALE/Hangman-v5', 'ALE/HauntedHouse-v5', 'ALE/Hero-v5', 'ALE/HumanCannonball-v5', 'ALE/IceHockey-v5', 'ALE/Jamesbond-v5', 'ALE/JourneyEscape-v5', 'ALE/Kaboom-v5', 'ALE/Kangaroo-v5', 'ALE/KeystoneKapers-v5', 'ALE/KingKong-v5', 'ALE/Klax-v5', 'ALE/Koolaid-v5', 'ALE/Krull-v5', 'ALE/KungFuMaster-v5', 'ALE/LaserGates-v5', 'ALE/LostLuggage-v5', 'ALE/MarioBros-v5', 'ALE/MiniatureGolf-v5', 'ALE/MontezumaRevenge-v5', 'ALE/MrDo-v5', 'ALE/MsPacman-v5', 'ALE/NameThisGame-v5', 'ALE/Othello-v5', 'ALE/Pacman-v5', 'ALE/Phoenix-v5', 'ALE/Pitfall-v5', 'ALE/Pitfall2-v5', 'ALE/Pong-v5', 'ALE/Pooyan-v5', 'ALE/PrivateEye-v5', 'ALE/Qbert-v5', 'ALE/Riverraid-v5', 'ALE/RoadRunner-v5', 'ALE/Robotank-v5', 'ALE/Seaquest-v5', 'ALE/SirLancelot-v5', 'ALE/Skiing-v5', 'ALE/Solaris-v5', 'ALE/SpaceInvaders-v5', 'ALE/SpaceWar-v5', 'ALE/StarGunner-v5', 'ALE/Superman-v5', 'ALE/Surround-v5', 'ALE/Tennis-v5', 'ALE/TicTacToe3D-v5', 'ALE/TimePilot-v5', 'ALE/Trondead-v5', 'ALE/Turmoil-v5', 'ALE/Tutankham-v5', 'ALE/UpNDown-v5', 'ALE/Venture-v5', 'ALE/VideoCheckers-v5', 'ALE/Videochess-v5', 'ALE/Videocube-v5', 'ALE/VideoPinball-v5', 'ALE/WizardOfWor-v5', 'ALE/WordZapper-v5', 'ALE/YarsRevenge-v5', 'ALE/Zaxxon-v5']
```

I think you can get the version `5` in "`-v5`" by using `value`, but I was too lazy to add that.

And I can't explain what is what because I hacked by way through so I don't understand my code either. If anyone do understand, please add more!